# In Razor select a IList<MenuNode> of nodes by a ParentId or TabId in DNN7

Tags: razor, dotnetnuke

Using DNN7 and trying to write a DDR Menu in Razor, My Menu Tree can be at time 5 Levels deep and wanted to know if there was a way to access a list of nodes by just passing a TabId or ParentId?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so figured it out should anyone else need this

```
@using DotNetNuke.Web.DDRMenu;
@using System.Dynamic;
@using DotNetNuke.Entities.Tabs;

@inherits DotNetNuke.Web.Razor.DotNetNukeWebPage<dynamic>
@{ 
    var tabs = TabController.GetTabsByParent(TabController.CurrentPage.TabID, TabController.CurrentPage.PortalID);
}

@RenderNodes(tabs)

@helper RenderNodes(IList<TabInfo> nodes)
{
    foreach (var t in nodes)
    {
        <div class="listing-repeater row">
            <div class="span17 listing-item">
                <h3>
                    <a href="@t.FullUrl">@t.TabName</a>
                </h3>
                <p>
                    <a href="#">@t.Description</a>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="span1">
                <span>
                    &rsaquo;
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    } 
}
```